# Having problems merging two images using ImageMagick, the error says that it can't find the images I'm trying to merge

Tags: zsh, imagemagick

I've tried looking for answers online, but none of the solutions I've found worked. So far I have tried the following three commands; where `a` and `b` are the images I want to merge and `c` is the combined image I want to create:

- `convert +append a.png b.jpg +append c.png`
- `magic convert a.png b.png +append c.png`
- `magick a.png b.png +append c.png`

But I just keep on getting the error says that it can't find the images I'm trying to merge when I run each of them.

I'm using the `/zsh/` cshell on macOS Big Sur (11.1) and, since I just downloaded it with Homebrew, I'm pretty sure I am using the latest version of ImageMagick.

Comment: I can successfully run this command `convert a.png b.png +append c.png` and this one `magick a.png b.png +append c.png`. Your first command seems to have `b.jpg` while the others have `b.png` so it seems like you are simply using the wrong filename in the commands. Look at the file names and try again. FWIW, `magic` is not a command; `magick` and `convert` are commands.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to do as you said I input "convert lin.png b.png +append c.png" and I get the errors "convert: unable to open image 'lin.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: unable to open image 'b.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: unable to open image 'b.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
convert: no images defined `c.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3301."

Comment: My post was simply a comment and not an answer. This issue is not that difficult: You need to use the *exact* filenames to do this: Is `lin.png` actually today `b.png` actually in the directory where you are running this command?

Comment: Those are the exact filenames yes. They aren't in the directory. Do I need to put them there or something? In that case how would I do so?

Comment: “They aren't in the directory. Do I need to put them there or something? In that case how would I do so?” Honestly, it sounds like you are in over your head. But it shouldn’t be too hard to get past this. When you open up Terminal, you are in your user’s home directory. So if the files aren’t there you need to copy them to your home directory. Or you can open up the Terminal and navigate to the directory where those images are. And then when in that directory run that command. I just posted an [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619415/167207) to explain what is happening; or not in this case.

Answer (score 1):

### You need to run that command in the directory where the files exist.

This command should work fine with no other tweaks:

```
convert a.png b.png +append c.png
```

If you are getting and error like this:

```
convert: unable to open image 'b.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537
```

That simply means what it says: If the program `convert` is unable to open the image `b.png`, that means the command can’t find the files.

Commands that require file interaction need to be able to access the file. So when you refer to `a.png` and `b.png` the expectation can be interpreted like this:

> “Convert should look for the files `a.png` and `b.png` and then convert will append one file to another and output `c.png`.”

So simply open the Terminal and go to the directory where those images are.

Or if you are confused about how to do that, when you open the Terminal it *always* lands you into your home directory. So just copy the files from wherever they are into your user’s home directory an then run the command.